# preventDefault() not working as desired

Tags: javascript, events

```
<script>
function confirmDel(evt)
{var con =false;
    con=confirm('Do you really want to remove this purchase?.');
    if(con)
    {
        return true;
    }else
    {
        event.preventDefault();
    }
}
</script>
```

my html

```
 <a title="View Log" onclick="return confirmDel(this);" href="index.php?mod=tech_support">delete</a>
```

above code works fine in chrome browser but fails in Mozilla .
but when i use `return false` instead of `event.preventDefault();` it works fine in both.
can anyone explain why this happens

Comment: Is this the actual code? Because I see `evt` and not `event`

Comment: Just what he said. This should not work in chrome.

Comment: @SoonDead it works in Chrome because it mimics old IE behavior (just like Chrome also has `innerText`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is with `event.preventDefault()`. The event you're passing is `evt`, not `event`. You have to use:

```
evt.preventDefault();
```

`event.preventDefault()` works in Chrome because it mimics old IE behavior for backwards compatibility (just like it also has `innerText`).

In old IE, the event object was `window.event`. So calling `event.preventDefault()` calls the global event object, which works in Chrome and IE, but not Firefox which doesn't implement this non-standard behavior.

Comment: thank you for this information i thought event property is available in all browser.

Comment: @ArunKillu no, it's an old IE behavior which doesn't follow any standard. This behavior is emulated in Chrome for IE compatibility, but not all browsers implement IE behaviors for such reasons.